# porting a c++ piece of code that does bit manipulation in python

Tags: python

```
int p[30];
for(int i=0,b=1;i<30;++i,b<<=1) p[i] = b;
```

How do we convert this piece of code to python?
We tried implementing the above using two for loops in python but couldn't get there .

```
for i in range(30):
    for b in range(b/=2):
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just setting `p` to `[1, 2, 4, 8, 16.....]`.

So `p = [1 << i for i in range(30)]`

Comment: Can you convert the whole piece into a working code with an example?

Comment: @jammy That's it. The line `p = [1 << i for i in range(30)]` accomplishes the same thing as your C++ code.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyChucky.  Yes.  This one line of code does precisely what your two lines of code did.  Rather than just blindly trying to convert C++ into Python, it was easier to say "what is this code doing"?

Comment: @jammy It may or may not be useful to note that in this *particular* case, you could also get the same result from `p = [2**i for i in range(30)]`, but that's using exponentiation rather than bit shifting.

Comment: @FrankYellin can you help us port this code in c++?

Comment: @jammy You asked a question; Frank Yellin answered it.  You've now edited your question and expanded it it so much that's now a different question, which is poor form. It would be better to ask a new question (and probably accept the answer to this one). You can link from one to the other if you feel that would be helpful.